# Updating a File in Subversion from a Jenkins Job

Tags: svn, jenkins

my group has a version file maintained within our svn environment that gets updated after every build (build performed by executing a Jenkins job). I would like to be able to automate

```
1) edit the file
2) after edit, re-commit the file to subversion
```

as a step within a Jenkins job. I was wondering whether there is a way to do this? I have perused earlier posts but cannot find one like this. Thanks for any response

Comment: This is really really really bad practice.

Comment: In general - you can always use any script to change the file, from ANT libraries to bash, Shell, etc. after edit you can use svn command from your command line \ Shell. you will need to make sure you have a client installed on the slave, you can automate it quite easily. I would definitely recommend keeping track on the versions in a different way, pushing or committing something back to the source control from the build phase is not a good practice.